# How to force log rotation more than one time in a day?

Tags: 14.04, apache2, logrotate

I'm trying to force the Apache logs rotations by executing `sudo logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/apache2`.

When I executed the command for the first time, I get the logs rotated correctly. But if I execute the command one more time minutes latter the logs aren't rotated at all. Don't suppose the `--force` option rotate the log no matter what the configuration is or if the rotation already was executed?